# Number of distinct bootstrap (re)samples with restriction

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, bootstrap

What is the number of distinct bootstrap (re)samples, when a specific element cannot appear more than 3 times in the resample ( or k times in general) ?

when k=n then we got the general solution: ${2n-1\choose n}$

Probability of not choosing specific element more than three times is $(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n-3} $

Then multiplying by n to get the probability of not choosing any element more than three times $ n \cdot(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n-3} $

Should I multiply this probability with ${2n-1\choose 3}$  ??

Comment: Why the restriction that an observation cannot appear more than three times? $//$ What if multiple observations are equal? Do you mean that observations or indices cannot appear more than three times? (I think you meant indices, but to see the difference, consider bootstrapping the set $\{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2\}$.)

Comment: Hi Dave sorry i mean indices.

Comment: I fugured you meant indices, but why the restriction about no index appearing more than three times?

Comment: I mean that a  specific element cannot appear more than 3 times in the resample

Comment: Why do you impose that restriction?

Comment: Its just a question no reason for imposing it.